# How to print a new line using an escape sequence

Tags: java, string

So I'm writing a program that generates a sentence using BNF grammar. So let's say that I had this for a grammar file:

```
<s>::=<np> <vp> 
<np>::=<dp> <adjp> <n>|<pn> 
<dp>::=the|a      
<adjp>::=<adj>|<adj> <adjp> 
<adj>::=big|fat|green|wonderful|faulty|subliminal|pretentious 
<n>::=dog|cat|man|university|father|mother|child|television 
<pn>::=John|Jane|Sally|Spot|Fred|Elmo 
<vp>::=<tv> <np>|<iv> 
<tv>::=hit|honored|kissed|helped 
<iv>::=died|collapsed|laughed|wept
```

and I ask it to print a random sentence, it would go to  and choose an option, let's say , and then say it chooses John. Then we are done with  because we hit a terminal and then we go to . Say it goes to  and then chooses laughed. We would get the sentence John laughed.

What I would like to do is add a p. Meaning paragraph. My formula for a paragraph would be something along the lines of

```
<p>::=<s> \n <s> | <p>
```

and I want that \n to appear as a new line, but instead my program prints it in the terminal as a \n instead of treating it as an escape sequence! What my program does is that it takes in each token and turns it into a string if it's a terminal, which \n is. Why isn't it working?
note: I can't show implementation details for my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can modify my program to read in the BNF lines as char[] arrays. This will allow it to interpret the escape sequences. Then I can convert the char array into a string and print it out. I hope this helps anybody who has had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<new_line> ::= '\x0A'
```

Then you can use it

Comment: my program still prints it as \x0A. In my program I need to concatenate this string with other strings, does that have to do with the problem?

Comment: @Yaknus should not. Try \x0A, '\n', '\x0A'

Comment: Oh, my program has to read it as a char. That's the problem. No wonder why it isn't working, is there anyway around this? It prints as '\x0A' since my program is reading it as a string still. Think of it like token based processing.

Comment: @Yaknus As a single char? Hmm, you can literally place an endline there, but I guess your program would think it's the end of the grammar line. You can do a trick and use some rarely used char as a newline, like `, but it's not a decent workaround

Comment: The grammar file is an external text file, so when my program goes through each line and parses it based on the "::=" and the " ", I get back a string array, meaning I need a way to print a newline through a string. Perhaps it isn't possible? I still feel like there should be a way.